# Does Haskell have "variables"? Or, easiest way to read configuration data?

Tags: haskell, immutability

I have written my medium-sized Haskell app with hard-coded config variables (like Google OAuth ClientId & ClientSecret). Now that I'm prepping the app for a production deployment, I need to move all these config variable out of the source, to either: (a) environment variables, or (b) a plain-text config file.

Here's what the code, currently, look likes:

```
googleClientId :: T.Text
googleClientId = "redacted"

googleClientSecret :: T.Text
googleClientSecret = "redacted"

generateOAuthUserCode :: IO (OAuthCodeResponse)
generateOAuthUserCode = do
  r <- asJSON =<< post "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code" ["client_id" := googleClientId, "scope" := ("email profile" :: T.Text)]
  return $ r ^. responseBody
```

What's the **fastest/easiest** way to get `googleClientId` and `googleClientSecret` from an environment variable (or config file)? I tried the following:

```
googleClientId :: T.Text
googleClientId = undefined

googleClientSecret :: T.Text
googleClientSecret = undefined

main :: IO()
main = do 
  googleClientId <- getEnv "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
  googleClientSecret <- getENV "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"
  -- Start the main app, which internally will call generateOAuthUserCode at some point.
```

The expectation was that the global `googleClientId` and `googleClientSecret` will be re-bound, but my editor immediately started showing a warning that "the binding shadows an existing binding", indicating that Haskell is creating a new binding, instead of changing the existing one.

So, two questions here:

1. First, the pragmatic one. How to solve the problem at hand, **without** getting into the Reader monad, which might involve changing a lot of function signatures across my app.
2. Second, the one oriented to learning. Haskell has immutable *values*, which is understood and appreciated. Does it even have immutable *variable binding*? Is it not possible to get dynamic variable bindings, like in Common Lisp?

**Edit:**  What about the following approach?

what about the following approach?

```
outerFunc :: String -> String -> IO ()
outerFunc googleClientId googleClientSecret = do
  -- more code comes here

  where
    generateOAuthUserCode :: IO (OAuthCodeResponse)
    generateOAuthUserCode = do
      r <- asJSON =<< post "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code" ["client_id" := googleClientId, "scope" := ("email profile" :: T.Text)]
      return $ r ^. responseBody

    -- more functions depending upon the config variables
```

Comment: Reading https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/443-A_Solution_to_the_Configuration_Problem_in_Haskell after posting this question.

Comment: first note that I don't think you'll get away without some medium refactoring - so one *easy* solution is to delete `googleClientId :: ...` and `googleClientSecret :: ...` (both definitions) completely, then look where the compiler is complaining about the missing items, move the identifiers into arguments in the so found functions and then provide the arguments where you have them from either arguments you already introduced or from the local values in your `main` ... TL;DR: make the configuration into arguments instead of global values

Comment: Since `generateOAuthUserCode` is already an `IO` action, you could just move the `getEnv` into the `do` block there, I think. Or is it just an example for lots of other global variables throughout your codebase? Then read my answer.

Comment: Added an alternative approach to my question.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I do not see the advantage of your new approach. Could you elaborate? Also, mind giving me feedback regarding my comment and/or answer? Not sure if I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I assumed that you rely on global variables like `googleClientId` often in your codebase.

*You might want to try and at least estimate the cost of the `Reader` approach before you go the "technical debt" route. Global variables are a bad practice anyways, @Carsten has proposed an alternative refactoring. But since you are asking for pragmatic help...*

Question 1: The **fastest/easiest** way is to use the frowned-upon `unsafePerformIO`. Like this:

```
googleClientId = unsafePerformIO $ getEnv "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
main = putStrLn googleClientId
```

This basically lets you ignore the safety of `IO` and puts the desired value into a global variable as if it was a plain string. Please note that `getEnv` *crashes* if the environment variable does not exist.

Question 2: One cannot "update" variables in Haskell. If one creates another variable with the same name in a nested scope, that binding will shadow the outer one in the inner scope, leaving the outer binding intact. That is somewhat confusing, hence the warning.

Comment: Use `lookupEnv`. Running `lookupEnv` with `unsafePerformIO` is safe.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I did not know `lookupEnv`. But in case of global variables, the OP probably does not want to change their type to `Maybe String`.

Comment: Well you can do `fromMaybe "" . unsafePerformIO $ lookupEnv "..."`

Comment: @Bakuriu That would cause failures later on, and obscure the root cause. Since those configuration variables are hard-coded right now, I assume there is no error handling whatsoever. I'd rather have a program crash right at the start then.

Comment: How do you handle exceptions thrown in IO action passed to `unsafePerformIO`? If you are practicing _fail fast_ then it's okay to not handle them.

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi I'm talking about a "quick and dirty" approach here. Fail fast, and rely on the environment variables being set correctly by whoever runs the program. Not very safe, clean or elegant, but the OP asked for the fastest/easiest way.

Comment: @stholzm should have mentioned OP, sorry.

Comment: It depends. Generally you have a default configuration value and the env variable is used to change that. So replace `""` with whichever default is sensible.

Comment: @Bakuriu depends on the config variable, I guess. Imagine using the wrong database or web service because you forgot to set the env variable! I'd rather fail fast. For other cases, `lookupEnv` and `fromMaybe` may be preferrable indeed.

Comment: Note that it's likely that the result of that environment lookup gets cached. That's probably ideal for this use case, but you wouldn't want to use the same technique for values that you expect to change.